# Are questions about trading and markets okay?

Tags: discussion

Are questions about trading and markets okay?

For example, could I ask "has there been any correlation between the monero price and amount of development activity in the past?"

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion, no. Answers on Stack Exchange should stick to facts and not seed discussions or opinionated replies.

In my role as a moderator, I would close this as [primarily opinion-based](https://monero.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions):

> Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than on facts, references, or specific expertise.

See also

- [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, yes. Though trading and markets is a secondary aspect to this currency, it is a part of it. Yes, some people are just dumbass speculators who don't care about Monero. But a good deal many more are people investing in a future where the world's currency is digitally secured.

We shouldn't ban investing talk, just deemphasize it.